# can't access cookie when page is iframed by shopify

Tags: iframe, cookies, shopify, hapi.js

I am running node v6.9.1 and i have a simple server running using hapi@16.0.1

I can set a cookie at route `/cookies/set` with the following code:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/cookies/set',
    config: {
        handler: (request: hapi.Request, reply: hapi.IReply) => {
            reply('cookie set').state('data', JSON.stringify({
                hasCookie: true
            }));
        }
    }
});
```

And retrieving the cookie at `/cookies/get` with the following code:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/cookies/get',
    config: {
        state: {
            parse: true,
            failAction: 'error'
        },
        handler: (request: hapi.Request, reply: hapi.IReply) => {
            reply({
                cookie: request.state
            })
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine when browsing locally. I setup another server running on a different port, with an index.html which iframes the cookie demo.

The iframe `src` is pointing to `http://localhost:9500/cookies/set` and then using dev tools, i redirect the iframe to `/cookies/get` and all is working fine - i can see the the `hasCookie: true` being returned.

I then setup a shopify embedded app which after authenticating with OAuth, redirects to `/cookies/set` and i get the response 'cookie set'

Again using dev tools, i redirect the frame to `/cookies/get` but this time the cookie is blank?

I'm getting no console errors or anything on shopify, and no errors on my side either. I've even got localhost running on https to make sure it wasn't some weird thing to do with framing a http page inside a https page.

Why can't i access the cookie? Why is it behaving differently than when i setup a different server and mimicked shopify's setup? (localhost:8000 is a different domain to localhost:9500, just like shopify.com is different to localhost)

I've tried numerous cookie/session libraries etc to no avail.

I've enabled 3rd party cookies.

I'm not doing any weird cross domain stuff - the iframed page is stand alone and doesn't need to know anything about the parent page.

I also tried having `/cookies/get` return a simple http page which makes an XHR request to `/cookies/get2` (same code) and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Would it make any sense that Shopify strips your cookies and there is nothing you can do about it?

Comment: I would certainly hope not. My site is in an iframe and the cookie is http only, so they don't have any access to it. i'm not doing any cross domain scripting, so they wouldn't even have a chance to intercept it.

Comment: I like how you set a cookie with a GET. Mindblown... :)